# Creating an empty array in PHP and later checking if it there is some valid elements at an index

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic-arrays

In Javascript I would do something like this-

```
var time_array = [];
if ((previousTime > time_array[i]) || (time_array[i] === undefined) )
{
     //Do Something
}
```

I want to do something similar in PHP

```
$time_array = array();
if (($previousTime> $time_array[$i]) || ($time_array[$i] === undefined) ))
{
    //Do Something

}
```

I can do this very easily in Javascript , but I am a little confused about it in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$time_array = array();
if (!isset($time_array[$i]) || $previousTime > $time_array[$i])
{
    //Do Something

}
```

It will **first check if the variable is set** and if it is not, the second condition will never be evaluated, so it's safe to use.

**Edit:** `isset()` checks whether a variable is declared and is set to a non-null value. You may want to use: `if ($time_array[$i] === null)` instead (that would be probably more similar to JS's `undefined`).

Comment: if you have `error_reporting(E_ALL)` on, then php will notify you of the undefined index, when using `if ($time_array[$i] === null)`, therefore I would suggest to not do that, and use isset() instead.

Comment: That's true, my bad. Thank you for your comment, @Hallur

Comment: `(!isset($time_array[$i]) || ($time_array[$i] === null) || ($previousTime > $time_array[$i]))` - I did something like this and it works for me

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_key_exists.asp

```
if (array_key_exists($i,$time_array))
 {
     echo "Key exists!";
 }
```